# iOS For Loops Printing Array

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to use a for loop to pick letters from an array of letters and then add them to a variable which will then be printed to a Label.

I've written this code, which uses a random number generator to select a random letter from the array and then should join it variable `password`. However it wasn't displaying anything in Label so I set a breakpoint inside the for loop to see what was happening but it doesn't even seem to be getting into the loop at all, e.g. it doesn't break inside it.

Here is the code I'm using

```
- (void) tapRecog:(id)sender
{
    @autoreleasepool 
    {

        NSString *password;
        NSArray *alpha = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", nil];
        int i, ran;

        for(i = 0;i == 3;i = i + 1)
        {
            ran = arc4random() % 3;
            password = [password stringByAppendingFormat:[alpha objectAtIndex:ran]];

        }

        displayPassword.text = password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not getting into your loop because you telling your for loop to run while i == 3. In the first segment of your for loop you are setting i = 0, then you are saying run while i == 3. Change the i == 3 to i < 3.

Comment: Ah, stupid Objective C confusing me. Thanks for the help. Will Accept answer in 9 minutes when I can

Comment: Strangely the code still doesn't work, although the For loop is now. The password string variable errors under debugging with `invalid CFStringRef`

Comment: See the other necessary fix in my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9750118/928098)

Answer (score 4):

A few things. First, you never initialise `password`, so when (or if, as per my second point) the code in your `for` loop runs, you'll have a problem...

Consider instead:

```
NSString *password = @"";
```

Also the condition in your `for` loop is wrong - the second statement, where you have `i == 3`, is the condition that must be `YES` for the `for` loop to continue; I suspect you mean:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```